# How to get all JSON object values from json string

Tags: json, jsp

```
{"role_id":2,"role":"user"},{"role_id":3,"role":"admin"},{"role_id":4,"role":"supeadmin"}
```

From this JSON String how can i get all the values in jsp page

Comment: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7197&lngWId=2

Comment: your json is invalid. post your json in http://json.parser.online.fr/. May your valid json is `[{"role_id":2,"role":"user"},{"role_id":3,"role":"admin"},{"role_id":4,"role":"supeadmin"}]`

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you need is Json API for java to parse json. Here's the useful link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/java-json-parser-example/

Answer (score 0):

[JSON-TAGLIB](http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/) is fairly straight forward and easy to use. Lots of examples available.